# Template cast to super class

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I want to be able to pass functions with an object of class **I** as parameter, where **I** inherits from **D**, to **FD** constructor::

```
class D {}; class I: public D {};
FD(std::function<void(D*)> f): _f(f) {}

void test(I*) { std::cout << "Success" << std::endl; }
FD fd(test); fd.call();
```

As I have been researching I should implement a [type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), but I do not know a clean way and did not find answers addressing type conversions appliable to my case.
Here is the full code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class D {}; class I: public D {};

class FD { 
  protected:
    std::function<void(D*)> _f;
  public:
    explicit FD(std::function<void(D*)> f): _f(f) {}
    void call() { _f(0); }
};

void test(I*) { std::cout << "Success" << std::endl; }

int main () {
  FD fd(test); fd.call();
}
```

I get:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:17:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘FD::FD(void (&)(I*))’
   FD fd(test); fd.call();
             ^
test.cpp:10:14: note: candidate: FD::FD(std::function<void(D*)>)
     explicit FD(std::function<void(D*)> f): _f(f) {}
              ^~
test.cpp:10:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void(I*)’ to ‘std::function<void(D*)>’
```

---

I have also tried using *int* and *double*:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class FD { 
  protected:
    std::function<void(double)> _f;
  public:
    explicit FD(std::function<void(double)> f): _f(f) {}
    void call() { _f(0); }
};

void test(int v) { std::cout << "Success" << std::endl; }

int main () {
  FD fd(test); fd.call();
}
```

With output:

```
Success
```

Comment: I'm surprised the case with `int` and `double` works, but it's probably because `int` and `double` are implicitly convertible to each other. `D*` is not implicitly convertible to `I*`, only the opposite is true. If you had `class I {}; class D: public I {};` instead it would work. Imagine if `I` had an extra member. It's not clear to what behavior you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello @FrançoisAndrieux, exaclty, what if *FD* were to call methods of I that were not in *D*? If an *I* were expected and a *D* were given, it would definetely crash. Maybe to give *I* when *D* is expected is forgiven to disallow less deterministic crashes?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to explain the reason for the compilation error in excruciating technical detail, and why you cannot do what you want to do, in C++, but perhaps this fundamental reason will be clear to you if you consider a very simple thought experiment:

```
std::function<void(D*)> f;
```

You surely understand that this callable object can be called using a pointer to ***any*** subclass of `D`. You might have some other class called `J` that also inherits from D, and so this is perfectly acceptable:

```
class J : public D {};

J j;

f(&j);
```

But you are attempting to do here is construct your `std::function` using a pointer to a function that takes only `I *` as a parameter:

```
void test(I*)
```

If what you were attempting to do was possible, then this will mean that this `test()` function can be called, via the `std::function<void (D*)> object`, using a pointer to `J`, instead of `I`. Fail. This is, of course, is not allowed in C++. If the only relationship between two classes is that they all have the same parent class, you simply cannot convert a pointer to one of them to a pointer to the other one. C++ does not work this way.

And the reason why your 2nd example, with `int`s and `double`s work, is because `int`s and `double`s ***can*** be converted to each other. The same is not true with pointers to two random classes. A pointer to a class can be converted to a pointer to a different class only in certain, well-defined cases. What you want is not allowed in C++.

The only thing that can happen here is the `test`() function taking a `D *` as a parameter, crossing its fingers and attempting to `dynamic_cast` it to an `I *` (assuming that `D` meets the requirements for a dynamic-castable class). And then you will have to decide what happens when this conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do the cast like this: `FD fd(reinterpret_cast<void(*)(D*)>(test));` but this is UB.

The error is clear - you can't implicitly cast `D*` to `I*`. This violates polymorphism.

Are you sure you are not mixing up `I` and `D`?

**UPD:**

I assume downvoting this post means it is not clear. I will try to explain:

Imagine the following:

```
class D
{
public:
    void (*ok)() = +[] { std::cout << "OK"; };
};

class I: public D
{
public:
    void (*not_ok)() = ok;
};
```

`ok()` can be accesed from `D` instance while `not_ok()` cannot. Now you want to call your function taking pointer to `I`. But that means your function can call `not_ok()` which is not valid for pointer to `D`:

```
void test(I* i)
{
    i->ok();
    i->not_ok();
}
```

With raw pointers you can try this:

```
class FD { 
  protected:
    std::function<void(D*)> _f;
  public:
    explicit FD(void(*f)(I*)) : _f(reinterpret_cast<void(*)(D*)>(f))
    {
    }
    void call() { _f(new I); }
};
```

It will print OKOK. But if you replace`new I` with `new D` it will fail on `not_ok()` call

This is why C++ doesn't allow to **implicitly** cast pointers (while you still can implicitly cast int to double).

Even if you want to 'hack' your code, C++ has no global type conversion rules. Also, you can't get raw pointer from std::function, therefore, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Hello espkk, the reinterpret_cast and replacing *I* as the father of *D* work. On the other hand your code with raw pointers works with **new I** instead of with **new D**. I gave you +1 thus someone else shall have been the -1. I will conjeture that the reason is that my code violates something different than polymorphism, otherwise *new D" should work instead of *new I" as you said.

Comment: @Matias Haeussler, thanks for noticing. Indeed, I mixed up things, I meant `new I`. Corrected now. So, `new D` won't work in this case (will cause a crash) because it is the base class which knows nothing about `not_ok` member. `new I` will work fine because it is derived from D and has both members